# How to interpret the term "Temporal Correlations"?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, reinforcement-learning

I'm not quite certain if I'm allowed to ask such a question but I'm getting desperate. English is not my native language and I'm unsure whether or not I am interpreting the following term correctly:

Temporal correlations.

The way I see it, is that certain captured data from environment `A` that have correlations so that estimated values from `z` can be derived from `x` and `y`. However, when capturing data from environment `B`, this is not the case at all. When samples from environment A are the majority of learning samples, the learning agent may not be able to correctly anticipate `z` in another environment like `B` because of, *how I am interpreting this*, temporal correlations in environment `A`.

Is this correct?

Comment: *Temporal* simply refers to temporality or time. In other words, based on time series data, correlations would be some local, time-based metric of dependence.

Comment: @MikeHunter so, just to be sure, if an online-learning agent is encountering only a specific situation (or environment) and learns from it for only a short amount of time, learning only things from this situation (or environment) thus "overfitting" on it and not being able to apply these experiences from on other situations (that occur later)?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand either the context you describe or your question.

Comment: @MikeHunter the term used in the abstract of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06574.pdf

Comment: Have you tried googling *temporal correlation* for an explanation?